# How to order Logon messages?

Tags: quickfix, quickfixn

For example I have config for QuickFix/n with several sessions. I have noticed that QuickFix/n sends `Logon` messages for these sessions in random order (but I am not sure of that).

Is it possible to set/configure a fixed order of `Logon` messages?

**Update**

I am integrating with a third-party FIX server. Their support said to me that I should send two `Logon` messages (for two sessions) in sequential order. Here is part of their message:

```
Please connect in the below order:

    1. Logon to STREAMING (35=A)
    2. Logon to TRADING (35=A)
    3. Subscribe to XXX/YYY on the STREAMING session (35=V) - Only on the streaming, as the trading session is for Orders / Trades only.
```

So, looks like I should send `Logon` to `STREAMING` session in first order and then send `Logon` to `TRADING` session in second order.

**Problem Solved**

The support team of third-party FIX server sent a message where they said that `Logon` messages should be send **simultaneously**. So, my decision (about sequential `Logon` messages) was wrong.

Comment: why do you have the need of configure the order of LOGON messages? QuickFix will do the work for you, all you need from your side will be to have the correct handlers for every message type

Comment: @stexcec Add section with explanation. Yes, It's looks strange to me too.

Comment: Never seen such message. Maybe you should ask their help desk for a working example. Did you try to reset the sequences at logon? Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485976/quickfix-n-error-msgseqnum-too-high/18490221#18490221